# How to get last (5) year ID with Linq group by and take()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I want to get  Budgetyear table of lasted 5 ID for 5 yearly plant result.My query is...

```
List<WorkCategories> query = new List<WorkCategories>();
            query = _context.REHPData.OrderByDescending(r=>r.BudgetYearID).Take(5).GroupBy(r => r.BudgetYearID).Select(s =>  new WorkCategories
            {
                ID = s.Key,
                Name = s.Select(r => r.BudgetYear.BudgetYearName).First(),
                Electrical = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 1).Count(),
                Mechanical = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 2).Count(),
                Civil = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 3).Count(),
                Admin = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 4).Count(),
                Vehicel = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 5).Count(),

            }).ToList();
```

But my result is wrong.Please help me teachers.....
This is Not include OrderByDescending(r=>r.BudgetYearID).Take(5) result is [image] This is include OrderByDescending(r=>r.BudgetYearID).Take(5) is wrong result is [image]

Comment: What is your data? What result do you currently get and why is it wrong? What is the expected result?

Comment: My result is example budgetyear table in 10 rows with ID 1-10.I want 1-5 ID with groupby and 1-5 ID included work categories nos show in table.But wrong result why...group by in problems i think..please help teacher...

Comment: You need to update your question to show a sample of the data, and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: above post edited image please help me teacher..

Comment: We do not know what the data is so cannot possibly help

Comment: This query is  `query = _context.REHPData.GroupBy(r => r.BudgetYearID).Select(s => new WorkCategories
            {
                ID = s.Key,
                
                Vehicel = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 5).Count(),
                
            }).OrderByDescending(s=>s.ID).Take(3).ToList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are performing your operations in the wrong order. If you do `OrderByDescending(`...`).Take(5)` before `GroupBy`, then you will take the 5 latest `BudgetYearId`s and combine them, so you will only process 5 rows.

I think you want:

```
List<WorkCategories> query = new List<WorkCategories>();
query = _context.REHPData.GroupBy(r => r.BudgetYearID)    
                .Select(s =>  new WorkCategories
                    {
                        ID = s.Key,
                        Name = s.Select(r => r.BudgetYear.BudgetYearName).First(),
                        Electrical = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 1).Count(),
                        Mechanical = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 2).Count(),
                        Civil = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 3).Count(),
                        Admin = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 4).Count(),
                        Vehicel = s.Where(r => r.WorkCategoriesID == 5).Count(),
                    }).OrderByDescending(s => s.ID)
                      .Take(5).ToList();
```